# jQuery div that follows cursor movement only within another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to be able to have a div which when the mouse is inside that div i get a small circular marker next to the cursor. When i move outside of this div the cursor marker is removed and is hidden.

I have found an example of what i want but not exactly what i need: -

http://jsfiddle.net/3964w/3/

Issues with the above:
- I only want the yellow marker to appear when im inside that div
- When im outside that div the marker is hidden and cursor is normal.
- The marker is too far away from the cursor when i move the mouse around

Any ideas?

```
var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0, limitX = 150-15, limitY = 150-15;
$(window).mousemove(function(e){
 mouseX = Math.min(e.pageX, limitX);
 mouseY = Math.min(e.pageY, limitY);
});

// cache the selector
var follower = $("#follower");
var xp = 0, yp = 0;
var loop = setInterval(function(){
// change 12 to alter damping higher is slower
xp += (mouseX - xp) / 12;
yp += (mouseY - yp) / 12;
follower.css({left:xp, top:yp});

}, 30);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you use css? Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/felipemiosso/3964w/30/

Just added `display:none;` on `#follower` and created a new style `.centerdiv:hover #follower { display:block; }`

To get the pointer fixed when the cursor stops, add `margin-left:-8px; margin-top:-8px;` to the `#follower`.

**Updated fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/felipemiosso/3964w/35/

**Updated fiddle 2** http://jsfiddle.net/felipemiosso/3964w/41/

Comment: thats great, thanks but is it possible to get the yellow circle fixed on the pointer?? Its for a hotspot area.

Comment: Fixed when the cursor stops or always fixed?

Comment: think ive sorted that issue but just looking at the fiddle and code. How would this work if i wanted multiple areas on the page and each div container was different sizes. var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0, limitX = 150-15, limitY = 150-15; what if the divs were all different sizes and i wanted multiple on a page?

Comment: Well, for multiplies areas with different sizes we will need to change the JS a litte bit. I updated the fiddle ...

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like, add `display: none` to the follower css and then: http://jsfiddle.net/3964w/32/

```
$('.container').mousemove(function(e){
$("#follower").show();
  var offset = $('.container').offset();

   mouseX = Math.min(e.pageX - offset.left, limitX);
   mouseY = Math.min(e.pageY - offset.top, limitY);
   if (mouseX < 0) mouseX = 0;
   if (mouseY < 0) mouseY = 0;
});

$('.container').mouseleave(function() {
        $("#follower").hide(); 
});
```

Comment: thats great, thanks but is it possible to get the yellow circle fixed on the pointer?? Its for a hotspot area.

Comment: Just add a little negative margin, e.g. `margin: -10px 0 0 -10px;` and that should do it: http://jsfiddle.net/3964w/34/

Answer (score 1):

the issue is in setInterval function which is called every 30msec
use the `onmousemove` when in div to get coordiantes. and show follower on `mouseenter`. hide on `mouseleave`

Answer (score 0):

change container  css properties

```
.anyclass{
    cursor: URL("smallcircle.png");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library, i found it really good.
http://www.tippedjs.com/