# circle following div issue on mousemove

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

At the moment I have some jQuery code telling a `div` called `small-circle` to follow my cursor around. I learnt how to achieve this from [a post on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19771047/jquery-div-that-follows-cursor-movement-only-within-another-div).

I modified the script very slightly to work with my own requirements. However there's is an issue when I add another `big-circle` to my `container` class. What seems to be happening is that the `id` of `small-circle2` is not allowed to move around inside of the `big-circle2` on the `x` axis. I'm thinking it has something to do with

```
var mouseXval = 0, mouseYval = 0, limitX = 120-30, limitY= 120-30;
```

`limitX` and `limitY` values might need to change because I am adding another `div` called `big-circle2` to the mix. So I tried this approach by adding `60` to `limitX = 120-60, limitY= 120-60;` but the only that changed was the placement of the circle. `small-circle2` was not following my cursor around on the `x` axis. Still only the `y` axis.

I'm thinking that the possible solution could be in the math that is going on inside of the `limitX` and `limitY` axises. Another problem could be trying to add multiple circles inside of the one `container`.

Here's the [fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/kapena/0L4boz65/3/)

Thank you!

Comment: Would this do what you're asking? https://jsfiddle.net/b5mbdojs/

Comment: Yes!! @blex please explain why `var pageOffset = $(this).offset();` solves this issue? Is it because `this` bound the gobal object?

Comment: `$(this)` will target the element you hover on, instead of selecting both as you did with `$(".big-circle, .big-circle2")`.

Comment: @blex great thank you for seeing that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thax to @blex I was able to see where I was off. As it turns out there was nothing wrong with the math in `limitX` and `limitY` and it was not a container issue. What was I thinking!

The problem was here inside of the `pageOffset` variable

```
// issue with selecting both classes
    var pageOffset = $(".big-circle, .big-circle2").offset();
```

The issue here was in selecting both `".big-circle, .big-circle2"` to trigger the `offset()`method. Instead of selecting each class and then applying `offset()` I should of used the `this` keyword to trigger any of the two circles I hovered on.

```
// use `this` to trigger the elements I hover on
    var pageOffset = $(this).offset();
```

When the user moves the mouse over `".big-circle, .big-circle2"` jQuery fires a callback function which is passed onto the `mousemove` event. As soon as our callback is fired jQuery sets the current scope to the DOM elements that **initiated the event** which in this case are `.big-circle` and `.big-circle2`. The cool part about all of this is that jQuery gives us access to the elements that initiated the `mousemove` event with the `this` keyword.

So we set `var offsetPage = $(this).offset();` and our `big-circle2` now has little circle that follows are cursor around.

```
// jQuery sets the scope of callback to `big-circle, big-circle2`
$(".big-circle, .big-circle2").mousemove(function(event){
// `this` accesses our elements 
var pageOffset = $(this).offset();
});
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kapena/0L4boz65/4/)